# Render on windows' desktop (background)

Tags: windows, directx, gdi+

is it possible to render to Windows' desktop (to overwrite the wallpaper)?
It wouldn´t be Windows if this was not possible, so there must be a way.

One i found out is, to call "GetDC()" with 0. But this draws on the top -
so all windows are overwriten.

I just want to overwrite the background wallpaper.
Is it possible to render there with DirectX (should be possible if with GDI+)?

Any suggestions? :)

Thanks
R

Comment: It is pretty pointless, whatever you draw isn't going to last long and will be wiped out when the desktop window redraws itself.  Look at the Rainmeter program source to find out how to create an always-on-the-bottom window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw on Windows 10 wallpaper in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132584/draw-on-windows-10-wallpaper-in-c)

Comment: Windows 10 did not exist at the time I asked this question, so not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It was possible before, MS killed the feature in Vista, and it no longer works.

AVS2 (visualization library in Winamp) used [IDirectDrawSurface7::Blt](https://web.archive.org/web/20140208225335/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg426181(v=vs.85).aspx) with DDBLT_COLORFILL flag to present stuff to desktop, with some setup code before that.

[Source code.](https://github.com/visbot/vis_avs/blob/master/avs/vis_avs/draw.cpp)  [What it did.](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-218710.html)